# Could this be a good alternative explanation as to why this subgroup is not empty?

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

> Show that if $H$ is a subgroup of $G_1$ and $K$ is a subgroup of $G_2$ then $H\times K$ is a subgroup of $G_1 \times G_2$.

Now here I'm trying to show that the set $H\times K$ is not empty. I could go with the ordinary way of showing this, which is to show that since $H<G_1$ and $K<G_2$, then it follows that there exists $(e_1,e_2)\in H\times K$. However I was wondering if an alternative explanation would be to say that since since $H<G_1$ and $K<G_2$, then $H$ and $K$ obviously are not empty, and since they aren't empty, it follows that their cartesian product is not empty either, thus proving the non-emptiness of $H\times K$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: It is exactly the same argument.

Comment: I believe writing $(e_1,e_2)\in H \times K$ is exactly what follows from your other argument.

Comment: In this case it's exactly the same argument. In *very* broad generalization the first argument (that the specific element $\langle e_1, e_2\rangle\in H\times K$) is marginally better because it doesn't depend on the axiom of choice: using the first argument with an explicit element you should be able to prove the corresponding theorem for an infinite product of groups. OTOH, without choice, the statement 'since they aren't empty, it follows that their cartesian product is not empty' no longer has to hold for an infinite cartesian product.

Comment: THey are the same argument because the *definition* of $A\time B = \{(a,b)|a\in A, b\in B\}$.  If $A, B$ are not empty then there exist at least one $a \in A$ and at least one $b \in B$ so $(a,b)\in A\times B$ and $A\times B$ is not empty.  In this case sub*groups* are never empty as they contain the identity element at least.  So $H\times K$ can not be empty.

Comment: Actually I prefer your first argument because I have the following issues with your second: "H<G1 and K<G2, then H and K obviously are not empty" why is that obvious?  and  "and since they aren't empty, it follows that their cartesian product is not empty either" why does that follow?  If you answer those (and they are easy to answer) then I am happy.  ... Although truth be told, I'm not sure I'd even *bother* to prove $H\times K$ is not empty; It'd probably take it for granted as being obvious.

Comment: Hmmm..... the key thing here seems to be the assumption that if $G_1$ and $G_2$ are groups then $G_1\times G_2$ is also a group.  That seems the much harder issue.  I do believe we can take it for granted (or at least trivial to prove) that if $A\subset C; B\subset D\implies A\times B\subset C\times D$.  And therefore if we have $H< G_1;K<G_2$ it follows by definiton $H\subset G_2;K\subset G_2$ so $H\times K\subset G_1\times G_2$. And as $H,K$ are groups so is $H\times K$ and we are done. No need to prove anything else *EXCEPT* that given any two groups, their cartesian product is a group.

Comment: It is not necessary to prove that the product is non-empty. What is necessary is to prove there exists an identity element. In fact, the existence of an identity element in a group is what precludes us from defining an empty group.